# What version of ember.js should I use for my project?

Tags: routes, ember.js

I am starting an evaluation of ember.js and I have identified quite a few resources. One of the things I noticed is that there are different ways to structure my application (e.g. using the router or not) and that the choice actually depends on the version of ember.js (the framework appears to be evolving very quickly).

I started off by downloading the reference version on the ember.js website (1.0.0-PRE2). However, if I understood correctly, what is described in the Guides section of the ember.js website corresponds to the latest version of the codebase on github. I am thinking about the new router API for instance.

So, I am wondering what is the recommended version of the framework for me to use in a new project. Should I use the master branch in github? Should I stick to 1.0.0-PRE2)? I am trying to get a sense for how stable/reliable the master is...

Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that the framework is evolving quickly. Which version to use depends on your tolerance for change and the delivery date of your project. If you need something stable and/or have to release soon then `1.0.0-PRE2` is the way to go.

That said, the new version of the router is stabilizing, I expect there to be a 1.0.0-PRE3 release in the coming weeks. If I were starting a new project I'd work from the Guides and go with the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

After many tests with the PRE 2, I started my developments with the latest version (GIT master) because the router v 2 is better and the integration with ember-data is easier. But, the API change quickly!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the starter-kit as a git submodule.

https://github.com/emberjs/starter-kit/tree/master/js/libs

This one also include the correct jQuery version